# Snow Leopard, App Store unable to download anything

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, install, mac-appstore

I am experiencing a weird problem, my Mac is running 10.6.8 and I want to download Mavericks, the problem is that when I click "Download" under the purchases tab, I enter my password and ... nothing happens. In fact it does the same thing for every app. Am I condemned to stay under Snow Leopard forever?
By the way I have been able to download and install Mavericks in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Years late, but to provide an answer...

You can only download the **current** OS X/macOS from the regular apps or search page.

If you require an older OS, then you must use your Purchase History & download it from there.

[image]

*Photoshopped to put these all next to each other*

El Capitan is slightly different, as it has been specially preserved by Apple due to Sierra not being compatible with older machines.

If you need El Capitan, it can be downloaded from the App Store - though it's difficult to actually search for.
See [Apple KB: Upgrade to OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/HT206886) which gives links that will open the correct location in the App Store app.

...or try this [**direct link**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9rnY.png)